# How to get campaign ID or referrer inside iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, idfa

I have iOS app and several ad campaigns for it. I build URLs for each campaign in iTunes connect (according to [that guide](http://help.apple.com/itc/appanalytics/#/itc201c43c63)) and it looks like that:

https://itunes.apple.com/app/apple-store/id0000000000?pt=0000&ct=&mt=8

Everything is OK and I can see statistics in App Analytics in iTunes Connect.

But is there any way to get campaign ID *inside* my app? I want to track that particular user install my app by clicking at some banner or link in newsletter and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you manage to get an answer for this?

Comment: @ViliusPau unfortunately not. Seems it's impossible.

Comment: I just wrote Apple to try and get an answer to this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is impossible. Apple prevents it.

There is a company that has patented one way to do it for advertising campaigns. It's expensive www.appsflyer.com

The "new" iTunes only gives you some information: https://www.nerdery.com/blog/itunes-connect-analytics-revolutionize-ios-app-marketing/